# Instantiated object scope and life time in PHP OOP

Tags: php, object

I want to know when an object in PHP will be destruct (destroy) by default. For example if we instantiate a class in a function, does it destruct at the end of function or still will be alive ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Object Life Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982051/php-object-life-time)

Comment: When you created this question there was a long list of suggested answers (many of them answer your question perfectly). Do not create questions when there already are answers!

Comment: @deceze you already posted it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will eventually be destroyed when all variables that point to the object cease to exist. Variables cease to exist when they go out of scope or when they are `unset`. Variables go out of scope when the scope/function they were declared in exits.

Comment: Why comment showing a clear dupe, but then answer? It's just feeding the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. The object will live for the duration that it's instance is in scope. You may wish to browse the [PHP Garbage Collection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) documentation. It's also worth noting that you can try these things out for yourself by implementing a [__destruct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.destruct) magic method.